How to disable caching of _custom_access callback
My module has several pages which use a custom access callback.  The conditions for access may change from call to call so this needs to be checked every time.  When I am logged in, the access callback seems to be accessed every time as expected, but when testing as an anonymous user, the access callback only executes once and then it seems the result is saved until the next time I manually clear caches.
I turned off caching on the route, but the _custom_access callback never is called for subsequent visits to the page unless I clear caches.
How can I make the access callback result not be cached?  Is that changed in routing.yml or in the access callback itself?
mtsxc.routing.yml
mtsxc.basic_search:
  path: '/test/search'
  defaults:
    _title: 'test Basic Search'
    _form: '\Drupal\mtsxc\Form\BasicSearchForm'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\mtsxc\securityCheck::access'
  option:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'


src/securityCheck.php
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

final class securityCheck{
  public function access(AccountInterface $account, Request $request){

  //some computations
  if($allowed){
    return AccessResult::allowed();
  }
  elseif(!$authenticated){
    return AccessResult::forbidden('NeedLogin');
  }
  elseif(!$agreed){
    return AccessResult::forbidden('NeedAgreement');
  }
}

src/EventSubscriber/mtsxcExceptionSubscriber.php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Drupal\mtsxc\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HttpExceptionSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

/**
 * @todo Add description for this subscriber.
 */
final class mtsxcExceptionSubscriber extends HttpExceptionSubscriberBase {

  protected function getHandledFormats() {
    return ['html'];
  }

  public function on403(ExceptionEvent $event) {
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    if ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException) {
      switch($exception->getMessage()){
        case 'NeedLogin': {
          $response = new RedirectResponse('/test/login');
          $event->setResponse($response);
          break;
        }
        case 'NeedAgreement': {
          $response = new RedirectResponse('/test/agreement');
          $event->setResponse($response);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

mtsxc.services.yml
services:
  mtsxc.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mtsxc\EventSubscriber\mtsxcExceptionSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }


What is the change in context which will trigger the change in access? I ask because you said it's only called once for anonymous users, which generally makes sense since all anonymous users usually will have the same permissions and context. So what context would change that would allow access to an anonymous user, when that anonymous user was previously denied access?

@Jaypan, The resource being accessed has a permission system separate from the Drupal system.  So they are not anonymous to the system but they are anonymous to Drupal and our system requirements are that they NOT have Drupal accounts.  So they need to sign in to this side authentication system and agree to terms and conditions before accessing the resource.  When they come anonymously it shows the login properly but when they login it then loops on the login page.  For logged in Drupal users, who also have to authenticate through the external system, the external login works perfectly.

BTW, if I clear the caches after the drupal anonymous person has logged in to the alternate system, then instead of being in the login loop, the next time they refresh their browser they are now logged in.   Likewise if the drupal anonymous person logs out of the alternate system, this is not recognized until the caches are cleared.

You could try moving your access checks into the form, that would ensure they're run each time

@unusedspoon, good idea, but since the same access checks need to happen on many different forms having the callback is more maintainable.

I found an answer that seems to work, verifying now, will accept answer if successful.
Change src/securityCheck.php to
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

final class securityCheck{
  public function access(AccountInterface $account, Request $request){

  //some computations
  if($allowed){
    return AccessResult::allowed()
            ->setCacheMaxAge(0);
  }
  elseif(!$authenticated){
    return AccessResult::forbidden('NeedLogin')
            ->setCacheMaxAge(0);
  }
  elseif(!$agreed){
    return AccessResult::forbidden('NeedAgreement')
            ->setCacheMaxAge(0);
  }
}


Does the external API set a cookie? If so, I'd add a cache context based on the cookie, rather than disabling caching altogether. https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts#core-contexts

Excellent.  I will look into that!
